# RabbitMq stopped receiving messages .Net Core

Tags: c#, docker, rabbitmq, .net-core

I am developing few services on **.Net Core** and I am using **RabbitMq** for sending messages between services. For receiving messages I build services inherited from  `IHostedService` which are connecting to RabbitMq and consume. Below you can find my base message receiver

```
public abstract class MessageReceiver<TMessage> : IMessageReceiver<TMessage>
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;        

    private Task _executingTask;

    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public string QueueName { get; private set; }

    private readonly IMessageHandler<TMessage> _handler;

    public MessageReceiver(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory, IMessageHandler<TMessage> handler, string queueName)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
        QueueName = queueName;
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var factory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConnectionFactory>();
            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
            var connectionModel = connection.CreateModel();
            connectionModel.QueueDeclare(QueueName, true, false, false, null);
            connectionModel.BasicQos(0, 100, false);
            var basicProperties = connectionModel.CreateBasicProperties();
            basicProperties.Persistent = true;

            while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(connectionModel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    _handler.Handle(body);
                };

                connectionModel.BasicConsume(QueueName, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_cts.Token);
        return _executingTask.IsCompleted ? _executingTask : Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _cts.Cancel();
        await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(-1, cancellationToken));
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
```

As you can see its generic, so I also build `IMessageHandler`which actually has implementation of our business logic - handling of received message

And here is one of message receivers

```
public class DemoReceiver : MessageReceiver<DemoMessage>
{        
    public DemoReceiver (IServiceScopeFactory factory, IMessageHandler<DemoMessage> handler) : base(factory, handler, QueueNames.Demo)
    {
    }
}
```

One more important thing - applications are running on **Docker**. So the issue is - I just noticed that sometimes its stoppes consuming messages from queue. So I see pending messages in RabbitMq queue dashboard. I dont know what can cause the issue. Maybe its `IHostedService` just 'sleep' and do not run. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: And why are you doing BasicConsume in a loop, every 5 seconds? You need this only once.

Comment: Thanks @Evk for reply. Good question. I read about IHostedService here https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-ihostedservice  and I thought it require to run background job in a loop

Comment: Well it does not. I'm not even sure how it should behave if you subscribe new consumer every 5 seconds. So I'd suggest to get rid of this first and see if that will fix your problem.

Comment: Yes @Evk it works without loop. I will deploy than changes and will wait a bit ... will see if it solves the problem. Many thanks !